How to cross compile in podman containers
Problem:
i have a c++ project and need to target multiple architectures. Also i need to link to various libraries on the target system. My target system is available as a multiplatform container. How can i easily setup a dockerfile that references the build container with my buildimage(e.g. amd64) and still can access my target arch (e.g. aarch64).
Current Approach:
my current setup is:
1 target system

target_system.dockerfile: i create a target system with podman build --platform where i install all my target dependencies and create a new image.
target_volume: from the create image i create a container. and from the container i create a snapshot that i then dump into a volume.

2 build system
i setup a container with build env and with cross_compiler and build tools.
3 actual build
for the actual build i mount the volume into the build container at (/target_root_filesystem/) set all my cross compiler flags and sysroot flags. Then run the build.
Question:
Is there a possibility to setup a container for aarch64 on an amd64 and setup another container with cross compiler toolchain without going trough the steps of creating a volume of my target system and then remount this into my build system.
Side-node:
yes i need the complete target root filesystem for linking as there are libraries in there that are not available in the package manager but added by the creator of the image.
It would be a very very big task to extract all he dependencies and copy the libraries by hand from the one container to the other with COPY in the dockerfile.
